# Instantiating from a class that has an array parameter in constructor in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, syntax

I have looked at several posts to reach an answer, but none came close enough.

I have a Q that might sound very empirical, and I am sure the answer is staring me in the face, but I am blinkered, I suppose!  I have a class named DrugExcretion with a constructor that has a parameter that is a reference to an array (named drugExcretionCode).

I can't seem to work out the **SYNTAX** to instantiate (i.e. create an object) in my main class named DrugExcretionApp.  Both classes are below:-

If anyone can direct me to a simple way to do this, it would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
public class DrugExcretion implements CautionInterface{

    int[] drugExcretionCode;
    private String[] drug;

    public DrugExcretion(String[] drug){
        this.drug = drug;
    }

    public String determineDanger(int[] drugExcretionCode){

    String site1 = "kidney";
    String site2 = "liver";
    String site;
    if (drugExcretionCode = 1){
        return "reduce dosage in elderly";
    }
    else{

        return "reduce dosage in children";
        }

}
}
```

x  -----------------  o  ----------------- x  -----------------  o

```
public class drugExcretionApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String drug1 = "enalapril";
        final String drug2 = "captopril";
        final String drug3 = "metoprolol";
        final String drug4 = "amlodipine";
        final String drug5 = "candesartan";

        String drug[] = {drug1, drug2, drug3, drug4, drug5};
        DrugExcretion listOne = new DrugExcretion(drug);


        DrugExcretion.determineDanger(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 1});
        }

}
```

I get an error "DrugExcretion cannot be resolved to a type" which initially made me think that the project setup was incorrect so the DrugExcretion class could not be seen by the app class - I rearranged the classes to keep them in the same package, but the error persists.

It appears to be a problem with access modifiers - have I made something static inadvertently???

BTW, the interface simply contains a signature of the only method in the first class.

Comment: Are both classes in the same package? if not you have to Import the exception class

Comment: What does your package structure look like?  Also, how are you compiling this code?  Via an IDE or on the command line?  If on the command line, are you specifying the classpath?

Comment: Hi Jens, yes as I mentioned, I put them in the same package as one attempt to sort it - no effect!

Comment: Hi Riann, Using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `determineDanger` like this:

```
listOne.determineDanger(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 1]);
```

`DrugExcretion.xxx` would be for a static method `xxx` of `DrugExcretion`. 
But `determineDanger` is an instance method, so needs to be invoked on an instance of the class, in this case `listOne`.

Comment: Hi Kevin,  thanks for your input - I had already changed the method invocation to "listOne.determineDanger(-------" from "DrgExcretion.determine------" before placing the above comment.

Comment: For interfaces to work, classes need to be general, or their methods cannot work (need subclasses that are more specific) therefore these classes need to be abstract i.e. they cannot be instantiated - I believe my class called DrugExcretion is too general, and is therefore seen as needing to be abstract AND to have method(s) that are unimplemented because of this.  BUT I WOULD LIKE TO HEAR FROM ANYONE WHO CAN SUPPORT/EXPAND ON THIS VIEW or REFUTE IT WITH FULL EXPLANATION Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are instantiating the `DrugExcretion` class, you need to call

`listOne.determineDanger(new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1 });`

Also, please check your code in the `DrugExcretion` class. It should be equals operator and not assignment.

```
if (drugExcretionCode == 1){
```

Comment: Thank you rslj, this has sorted some of the errors - I still get an error with "DrugExcretion" being underlined (with zigzag line) and error "DrugExcretion cannot be instantiated".

Comment: Hi all helpful experts, I have made a little progress (after a well-deserved break with cup of tea!!) - Apparently, the reason I was not able to instantiate the DrugExcretion class with an object was apparently because the interface needed to be an abstract class OR it had to have an unimplemented method - however, if I added the modifier "abstract" to the interface name and/or added an automated unimplemented method, the errors disappeared, but on running the program terminated.  ANY IDEAS AS TO SOLUTION NOW ANYONE? Many thanks!